# Convert VB code after framework update

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, compiler-errors

The framework has recently been updated on my computer and I've updated from Visual Studio 2008 to 2010, now there is a part of my code that won't work.

```
Public Property ItemCount() As Integer
        Get
            Dim val As Object = ViewState("ItemCount")
            Return If(val IsNot Nothing, CInt(val), 0)
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            ViewState("ItemCount") = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

The "Return If(val IsNot Nothing, CInt(val), 0)" part of the code does not work 
ERROR: 
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: BC30201: Expression expected.

Source Error:

Line 21:         Get 
Line 22:             Dim val As Object = ViewState("ItemCount") 
Line 23:             **Return If(val IsNot Nothing, CInt(val), 0)** 
Line 24:         End Get 
Line 25:      Set(ByVal value As Integer

Is there a converter that I can use to bring this part of the code upto date, I'm assuming is the code that's now been outdated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
Get
        Dim val As Object = ViewState("ItemCount")
        ' Return If(val IsNot Nothing, CInt(val), 0)
        If val Is Nothing Then
            Return 0
        Else
            Return (CInt(val))
        End If

    End Get
```

Try This, it should work.